# How to see the directories etc, bin, boot in the file system?

Tags: filesystem

I am new to Ubuntu and I am unable to see the files in `/etc`, `/bin` and `/boot`. I want to know by using which command I can see them?

I have tried logging in as root `sudo -s` and `tree` command but unable to view them.

Comment: You could try `ls /`. Hope that helps.

Comment: @mikewhatever, Yes it worked. But what is the significance of this command? And why cant I browse them from "Files" in desktop?

Comment: Sure you can. / is accessible from the file browser in Ubuntu. ...not sure the command it really very significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directories you are looking for are in /

```
cd  /
ls  -l
```

This is a screenshot with the tree:

[image]

You don't need to use sudo for reading them (you would need it for writing in some of them)

I've posted 2 commands; I had a problem with end of line

Answer (score 1):

By default, the file browser (nautilus) opens a window in your home directory. Under the "Files" icon in the launcher, default directories inside your home directory are listed. On the left pane in a nautilus window however, there is a section "devices". Under Devices, you will find "Computer". Click on it and you will see all directories from the system's root directory, including the directories you mention.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a basic command tutorial like this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal